# Cannot Close Browser in DrissionPage

Tags: python, python-3.x, seleniumbase

I have move from Selenium/SeleniumBase to DrissionPage for it's Undetectable Ability. Everything was easy to understand. Except the last part of it. That is Closing the Browser. The [Docs](https://g1879.gitee.io/drissionpagedocs/ChromiumPage/page_operation/#quit) says that `page.quit()` would close the browser. But When I run it in my local machine I get this error:

```py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\chromium_driver.py", line 123, in _recv_loop
    message = loads(message_json)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here's The least of code:

```py
from DrissionPage import ChromiumPage
from time import sleep

page = ChromiumPage()
page.get('https://www.google.com/')

sleep(5)
page.quit()
```

My specs are:

```json
{
    "OS": "Windows 10 64 Bit",
    "OS_Version": "10.0 Build (10240)",
    "Browser": "Google Chrome",
    "Browser Version": "120.0.6099.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)"
}
```

How to fix this error and close it? Or, is there any alternative way to close it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of DrissionPage, thank you for liking my work.
Version 4.0 is fine. Now in beta, the latest is 4.0.0b26.

```
pip install DrissionPage==4.0.0b26
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, The best idea I have is to close `chrome.exe` using `psutil`.
Install it using:

```
pip install psutil
```

Then, `import psutil` in your code.
After that, replace the default `quit()` function with this one:

```py
page.quit = lambda: [proc.kill() for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name().__contains__('chrome')]
```

**Or** If you don't understand this one lined function, you can use this one:

```py
def manual_quit():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name().__contains__('chrome'):
            proc.kill()

page.quit = manual_quit
```

#### Disadvantages

**This function will close the Automated Chrome Browser as well as the Real Chrome Browser opened by you.** To prevent that, you can make a list of `pid` ids of chrome process at the beginning of your script before opening automated browser. Then when you want to close the browser, exclude the chrome process that has the matching `pid` ids of the list. In this way, only the chrome process started by your script will close (if you don't open any chrome process/tab/browser during the execution of your script).